# access data of observable collection to another observable collection

Tags: c#

i am try to copy loadcity oberservable collection to another observable collection which will be bind to xaml tag i am using MVVM architect

```
class CarLoader
   {
        public static async Task<ObservableCollection<CarModel>>LoadCity()
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => {
                return new ObservableCollection<CarModel>()
                {
                    new CarModel() {CarID=1,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=2,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=3,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},
                    new CarModel() {CarID=4,Brand="mehran",Make="suzuki" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=5,Brand="mehran2021",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=6,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},
                    new CarModel() {CarID=7,Brand="toyota",Make="toyata2020" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=8,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"},new CarModel() {CarID=9,Brand="toyota yaris",Make="toyata" ,Detail="electric car"}
                };
            });
        }   
    }
```

This is another class in I try to access

```
public async Task<ObservableCollection<CarModel>> LoadCarListAsync()
{
    CarList = await CarLoader.LoadCity();
    return CarList.ToString();  
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: `return CarList.ToString();` <-- this is not a meaningful operation.

Comment: @SelimYildiz see it again make some changes

Comment: @Dai make some changes check it now

Comment: There is **no reason** for using `await Task.Run()` here, just do `return new ObservableCollection { etc }`. You don't have any _real_ async code at all... so what are you _really_ trying to do?

Comment: @Dai i want to get that data in another observableCollection carList which is in different class